# Paypal API get invoices list with items

Tags: api, paypal, invoice

I'm searching a way to obtain the items list into the invoice from Paypal API.

I'm using V2 endpoint: https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices?page=1&page_size=100

and I also tried to append the fields list in the query string without success:
https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices?page=1&page_size=100&fields=items

This is the documentation about the invoice:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/v2/#definition-invoice

and the items array should be present but this is what I get:

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "id": "INV2-2RY8-ENR4-CNQU-JXPW",
        "status": "DRAFT",
        "detail": {
            "reference": "deal-ref",
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "note": "Thank you for your business.",
            "memo": "This is a long contract",
            "invoice_number": "#1234",
            "invoice_date": "2018-11-12",
            "payment_term": {
                "due_date": "2018-11-22"
            },
            "viewed_by_recipient": false,
            "group_draft": false,
            "metadata": {
                "create_time": "2021-01-28T11:27:22Z"
            }
        },
        "invoicer": {
            "email_address": "sb-fle2y4542126@business.example.com"
        },
        "primary_recipients": [
            {
                "billing_info": {
                    "name": {
                        "given_name": "Stephanie",
                        "surname": "Meyers",
                        "full_name": "Stephanie Meyers"
                    },
                    "email_address": "bill-me@example.com"
                },
                "shipping_info": {
                    "name": {
                        "given_name": "Stephanie",
                        "surname": "Meyers",
                        "full_name": "Stephanie Meyers"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "74.21"
        },
        "due_amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "74.21"
        },
        "links": [
            {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-2RY8-ENR4-CNQU-JXPW",
                "rel": "self",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-2RY8-ENR4-CNQU-JXPW/send",
                "rel": "send",
                "method": "POST"
            },
            {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-2RY8-ENR4-CNQU-JXPW",
                "rel": "replace",
                "method": "PUT"
            },
            {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-2RY8-ENR4-CNQU-JXPW",
                "rel": "delete",
                "method": "DELETE"
            },
            {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-2RY8-ENR4-CNQU-JXPW/payments",
                "rel": "record-payment",
                "method": "POST"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "INV2-RE4A-3KKC-C6Y6-96HG",
        "status": "MARKED_AS_PAID",
        "detail": {
            "reference": "deal-ref",
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "note": "Thank you for your business.",
            "memo": "This is a long contract",
            "invoice_number": "#123",
            "invoice_date": "2018-11-12",
            "payment_term": {
                "due_date": "2018-11-22"
            },
            "viewed_by_recipient": false,
            "group_draft": false,
            "metadata": {
                "create_time": "2021-01-26T13:41:31Z"
            }
        },
        "invoicer": {
            "email_address": "sb-fle2y4542126@business.example.com"
        },
        "primary_recipients": [
            {
                "billing_info": {
                    "name": {
                        "given_name": "Stephanie",
                        "surname": "Meyers",
                        "full_name": "Stephanie Meyers"
                    },
                    "email_address": "bill-me@example.com"
                },
                "shipping_info": {
                    "name": {
                        "given_name": "Stephanie",
                        "surname": "Meyers",
                        "full_name": "Stephanie Meyers"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "74.21"
        },
        "due_amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "0.00"
        },
        "payments": {
            "paid_amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "74.21"
            }
        },
        "links": [
            {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-RE4A-3KKC-C6Y6-96HG",
                "rel": "self",
                "method": "GET"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"links": [
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices?page=1&page_size=100&total_required=false",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    ]
}
```

By using the endpoit to get only one invoice I get the items:

```
{
"id": "INV2-2RY8-ENR4-CNQU-JXPW",
"status": "DRAFT",
"detail": {
    "reference": "deal-ref",
    "currency_code": "USD",
    "note": "Thank you for your business.",
    "memo": "This is a long contract",
    "additional_data": "2-4",
    "category_code": "SHIPPABLE",
    "invoice_number": "#1234",
    "invoice_date": "2018-11-12",
    "payment_term": {
        "term_type": "NET_10",
        "due_date": "2018-11-22"
    },
    "viewed_by_recipient": false,
    "group_draft": false,
    "metadata": {
        "create_time": "2021-01-28T11:27:22Z",
        "last_update_time": "2021-01-28T11:27:22Z",
        "created_by_flow": "REGULAR_SINGLE",
        "recipient_view_url": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/invoice/p/#2RY8ENR4CNQUJXPW",
        "invoicer_view_url": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/invoice/details/INV2-2RY8-ENR4-CNQU-JXPW",
        "caller_type": "API_V2_INVOICE"
    },
    "archived": false
},
"invoicer": {
    "name": {
        "given_name": "David",
        "surname": "Larusso",
        "full_name": "David Larusso"
    },
    "address": {
        "address_line_1": "1234 First Street",
        "address_line_2": "337673 Hillside Court",
        "admin_area_2": "Anytown",
        "admin_area_1": "CA",
        "postal_code": "98765",
        "country_code": "US"
    },
    "email_address": "sb-fle2y4542126@business.example.com",
    "phones": [
        {
            "country_code": "001",
            "national_number": "4085551234",
            "phone_type": "MOBILE"
        }
    ],
    "website": "www.test.com",
    "tax_id": "ABcNkWSfb5ICTt73nD3QON1fnnpgNKBy- Jb5SeuGj185MNNw6g",
    "additional_notes": "2-4",
    "logo_url": "https://example.com/logo.PNG"
},
"primary_recipients": [
    {
        "billing_info": {
            "name": {
                "given_name": "Stephanie",
                "surname": "Meyers",
                "full_name": "Stephanie Meyers"
            },
            "address": {
                "address_line_1": "1234 Main Street",
                "admin_area_2": "Anytown",
                "admin_area_1": "CA",
                "postal_code": "98765",
                "country_code": "US"
            },
            "email_address": "bill-me@example.com"
        },
        "shipping_info": {
            "name": {
                "given_name": "Stephanie",
                "surname": "Meyers",
                "full_name": "Stephanie Meyers"
            },
            "address": {
                "address_line_1": "1234 Main Street",
                "admin_area_2": "Anytown",
                "admin_area_1": "CA",
                "postal_code": "98765",
                "country_code": "US"
            }
        }
    }
],
"items": [
    {
        "id": "ITEM-9D199841WF5879731",
        "name": "Yoga Mat",
        "description": "Elastic mat to practice yoga.",
        "quantity": "1",
        "unit_amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "50.00"
        },
        "tax": {
            "id": "TAX-7JU53623DY541294B",
            "name": "Sales Tax",
            "percent": "7.25",
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "3.27"
            }
        },
        "discount": {
            "percent": "5",
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "-2.50"
            }
        },
        "unit_of_measure": "QUANTITY"
    },
    {
        "id": "ITEM-4TV13589DH284484Y",
        "name": "Yoga t-shirt",
        "quantity": "1",
        "unit_amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "10.00"
        },
        "tax": {
            "id": "TAX-7JU53623DY541294B",
            "name": "Sales Tax",
            "percent": "7.25",
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "0.34"
            }
        },
        "discount": {
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "-5.00"
            }
        },
        "unit_of_measure": "QUANTITY"
    }
],
"configuration": {
    "tax_calculated_after_discount": true,
    "tax_inclusive": false,
    "allow_tip": true,
    "partial_payment": {
        "allow_partial_payment": true,
        "minimum_amount_due": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "20.00"
        }
    },
    "template_id": "TEMP-4JC7006465773450S"
},
"amount": {
    "breakdown": {
        "item_total": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "60.00"
        },
        "discount": {
            "invoice_discount": {
                "percent": "5",
                "amount": {
                    "currency_code": "USD",
                    "value": "-2.63"
                }
            },
            "item_discount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "-7.50"
            }
        },
        "tax_total": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "4.34"
        },
        "shipping": {
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "10.00"
            },
            "tax": {
                "id": "TAX-4CC09681KH001992P",
                "name": "Sales Tax",
                "percent": "7.25",
                "amount": {
                    "currency_code": "USD",
                    "value": "0.73"
                }
            }
        },
        "custom": {
            "label": "Packing Charges",
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "10.00"
            }
        }
    },
    "currency_code": "USD",
    "value": "74.21"
},
"due_amount": {
    "currency_code": "USD",
    "value": "74.21"
},
"links": [
    {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-2RY8-ENR4-CNQU-JXPW",
        "rel": "self",
        "method": "GET"
    },
    {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-2RY8-ENR4-CNQU-JXPW/send",
        "rel": "send",
        "method": "POST"
    },
    {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-2RY8-ENR4-CNQU-JXPW",
        "rel": "replace",
        "method": "PUT"
    },
    {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-2RY8-ENR4-CNQU-JXPW",
        "rel": "delete",
        "method": "DELETE"
    },
    {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-2RY8-ENR4-CNQU-JXPW/payments",
        "rel": "record-payment",
        "method": "POST"
    }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve the items list without to process the invoices one by one?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> &fields=items

Items, in this context, means the invoices themselves as part of the list of results.

> Is there a way to retrieve the items list without to process the invoices one by one?

There isn't. You have to request an invoice individually.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Is there a documentation about how to pass the fields list? Could be items.items?